# How can I access my Pi that is connected to a 3G network from the outside Internet?

Tags: raspbian, networking

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian

The Raspberry Pi is connected to internet via a 3G USB Dongle.

I can access internet via this 3G dongle.

How can I now access the RasPi from "outside" i.e. the internet.  Seems to me that I need "port forwarding" which seems to make sense when I have a router.  When using a 3G connection I don't have a router so what are my options?

I would like to be able to SSH into my RasPi.

Comment: What do the following commands return? `ifconfig -a` and `traceroute google.com`

Comment: @Morgan - Please see the ifconfig & traceroute results here - 
http://pho.to/7RMN0

Comment: OK, I assume your 3G USB adapter is the interface `ppp0`. To access the Internet, there is only your 3G adapter, right? Can you ping `10.175.79.167` from outside your network? Could you paste the restult of `route` from the RPi? (maybe to be prepended by `sudo`)

Comment: Try using TelNet - It may help!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the most Telco operators do "Carrier grade NAT" here to hide a lot of costumers behind the same IP. You can't influence that to open the SSH Port.

One option is to use a Telco provider which provide a real IP address(really rare). Some Telcos offer special APNs which provide you a global unique IP Address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hamachi to create a VPN and connect your PC and the Raspberry to the same network. You can then access your Rpi via SSH.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts and specific details of the answer here, and provide a link(s) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use an IPv6 address as described in the blog of [Peter Mount](http://blog.retep.org/2013/08/20/getting-ipv6-working-on-the-uk-mobile-network/).
I followed the instructions and I can ssh into my RasPi which has a Huawei E160 3G dongle.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a global unique IP address i.e. you're not behind your ISP's NAT, you should be able to connect directly using your IP address assuming SSH is enabled on your Pi and accepting connections.

If you do not have a unique address, consider using a service like [Weaved](http://www.weaved.com/) which works similar to TeamViewer in that it allows connections through routers without port-forwarding.